# Tag Overflow occurs in the one boxed user

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

> **Note**: for me it happens only if the window width is less than 1242 px; the monitor width is 1920 in px

E.g.

> [image]

As you can see, something bad has happened to the [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) tag and it is split and also get overflown to the next line, out of the user card.

The tag badge is probably the cause.

Comment: Browser / OS? Direct link to chat-boxed profile would help too.

Comment: @Home http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3585782#3585782; Safari 7 on Mac OS 10.9. WAIT, it only occurs with the small window with... editing

Comment: Thanks. Same here in Chrome.

Comment: @Home Ok; sorry for giving the wrong link.

Comment: I don't see what you put in your online shrine to Oded, happen

Comment: @san WTF?​​​​​​

Comment: I don't see that overflow on my screens

Comment: @san Have you read the note? Oh, mistake there; just edited.

Comment: yup, and the same

Comment: I kinda like how it does that, but yea it's a valid bug report

Answer (score 2):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

[image]

But really, all that's needed is `display: inline-block` on the `a`.

Comment: But what will that do if there's physically not enough space?

Comment: @James Wasn't a clearfix a given?